# android UI many states switch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, switch-statement, android-seekbar

I need 4 states switch (with possibility to extend to more states). Standard Android Switch has only 2 (on/off). I wanted to use seekbar but it works terribly bad if I use ViewPager (two elements for sweeping - seekbar and viewpager).

Any idea how to create a nice many states switch then (only one state from all can be selected at the same time - exclusive states)?

Answer (score 1):

A [`Spinner`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) is a good UI element for providing an amount of selectable options that a user is able to pick a single one from.

On the other hand a [`RadioGroup`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) with [`RadioButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html)s could give a different UI element with the same result.

Comment: It's some kind of solution but I would prefer to have everything in the screen without any pullup lists....

Comment: I've added another alternative.